# c++ Pad sides of existing C array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a C array, i.e. `<type>* myarray`, that is logically a `<type>* myarray[#][#]`. It is the data from an RGBA image. I want to enlarge the "image" by shifting the contents by `offsetx, offsety` and filling the extra space with zeros.

```
01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08
09 10 11 12
```

with offset `1, -1` yields

```
00 01 02 03 04
00 05 06 07 08
00 09 10 11 12
00 00 00 00 00
```

There is obviously an efficient way to do this, but I'm stumped.

Edit01: I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
/**
 * @brief Shifts the src image by offset(x,y) into the dst_img.
 * @param src_img   Pointer to image data with pixels of arg_type. I.e., an
 * RGBA8888 image would be arg_type = Uint8.
 * @param dst_img   Pointer to output image data. **Must** be sized to fit the source image
 * plus the magnitude of the offsets. I.e. a 2x2 source with 1,-1 offsets requires a
 * 3x3 dst.
 * @param src_h         Height of the source
 * @param src_w         Width of the source
 * @param src_channels  Number of channels per pixel. I.e. RGBA8888 -> 4, HSV32f32f32f -> 3.
 * @param offset_y      Vert. offset
 * @param offset_x      Horiz. offset
 */
template <typename arg_type>
void shift_image(arg_type* src_img, arg_type* dst_img,
                 Uint32 src_h, Uint32 src_w, Uint32 src_channels,
                 int offset_y, int offset_x) {
    Uint32 src_pixels = (src_h * src_w * src_channels);
    std::valarray<arg_type> srcval = std::valarray<arg_type>(src_img,
                                                             sizeof(arg_type) * src_pixels);

    Uint32 dst_pixels = (src_h + abs(offset_y)) * (src_w + abs(offset_x)) * src_channels;
    std::valarray<arg_type> dstval =  std::valarray<arg_type>((arg_type)0,
                                                              sizeof(arg_type) * dst_pixels);

    std::slice srccolslice = std::slice(0, src_w * src_channels, 1);
    std::slice dstcolslice;
    if (offset_y < 0 ) {                            // Top   Row -> Top   Row
        for (Uint32 y = 0; y < src_h; y++) {        // Left  Col -> Left  Col
            if (offset_x < 0) {
                dstcolslice = std::slice(0, src_w * src_channels, 1);
            } else {                                // Right Col -> Right Col
                dstcolslice = std::slice(offset_x, (src_w + offset_x)  * src_channels, 1);
            }
            dstval[y][dstcolslice] = srcval[y][srccolslice];
        }
    } else {                                        // Bot   Row -> Bot   Row
        for (Uint32 y = 0; y < src_h; y++) {        // Left  Col -> Left  Col
            if (offset_x < 0) {
                dstcolslice = std::slice(0, src_w, 1);
            } else {                                // Right Col -> Right Col
                dstcolslice = std::slice(offset_x, (src_w + offset_x) * src_channels, 1);
            }
            dstval[y + offset_y][dstcolslice] = srcval[y][srccolslice];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No magic way to do it.  Just create a second, bigger 2D array, `memset` it to 0, and then copy the contents of the first 2D to the second...

Comment: Have you tried the simple approach of allocating a new array, and then filling its elements with either zero, or the corresponding element from `myarray`?  Why don't you try that and post if you encounter problems.

Comment: @NicholasM, That was what I did initially, but the nested loops and ifs seemed insane. My insufficient grasp of the pointer math prevents a more accurate description of the problem.

Comment: @justinzane Not sure why you need if conditions. All you need is 2 for loops. If the data is stored linearly in memory, all you would need is one loop + std::memcpy

Comment: suggestion: making the array 1D will greatly simplify the idea of this for you. Remember that to access an index `[x][y]` in a ID array you do `[x + y * (length of row)]`.

Comment: @Smac89 My problem with the 1D array analogy is that I then need to "insert" the zero elements into the array every column. Which requires vectors (or another dynamic construct), which seems like a highly inefficient way to do this.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili Conditionals are required since the x and y offsets can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I haven't understood the operations properly, but

1) Shouldn't the line in your code have the second slice argument be `src_w * src_channels` rather than `src_w`?  (If subclause in else clause).

```
dstcolslice = std::slice(0, src_w, 1);
```

2) If that is so, then isn't the entire set of if-loops equivalent to the following?

```
offset_y = (offset_y >= 0) ? offset_y : 0;
offset_x = (offset_x >= 0) ? offset_x : 0;

for (Uint32 y = 0; y < src_h; y++) {
  dstcolslice = std::slice(offset_x, (src_w + offset_x)  * src_channels, 1);
  dstval[y + offset_y][dstcolslice] = srcval[y][srccolslice];
}
```